# GraphQL-Java support for complex filters

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Does anyone know whether the Java GraphQL implementation (graphql-java) supports complex filters.  If I have understood this post correctly:

https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3/

The reference implementation includes filter argument is a built in argument which supports complex filters with nested conditions.  However these examples do not work with the graphql-java examples.

This is the simple example I am playing with using graphql-java:2.3.0:

```
    GraphQLType employeeType = newObject()
            .name("Employee")
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("name")
                    .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                    )
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("age")
                    .type(Scalars.GraphQLInt)
                    )
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("active")
                    .type(Scalars.GraphQLBoolean)
                    )
            .build();

    GraphQLObjectType companyType = newObject()
            .name("Company")
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("name")
                    .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                    )
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("employees")
                    .type(new GraphQLList(employeeType))
                    .argument(newArgument()
                            .name("name")
                            .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .argument(newArgument()
                            .name("age")
                            .type(Scalars.GraphQLInt)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .argument(newArgument()
                            .name("active")
                            .type(Scalars.GraphQLBoolean)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .dataFetcher(new EmployeeFetcher())
                    )
            .build();

    GraphQLObjectType companyListType = newObject()
            .name("Companies")
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                    .name("companies")
                    .type(new GraphQLList(companyType))
                    .argument(newArgument()
                                .name("name")
                                .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                                .build()
                            )
                    .dataFetcher(new CompanyFetcher())
                    )
            .build();


    GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
            .query(companyListType)
            .build();

    GraphQL graphQL = new GraphQL(schema);
```

Comment: hi @Shahin Askari, have you found anything that could help resolving this question? Any suggestion/links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: No we have not.  Based on my initial research it does not exist, I wanted to confirm here and kaqqao seems to agree.  Given this, and other limitations, we are choosing to come back to GraphQL later in the project for another review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is Graph.cool's extension, not the reference implementation. You can of course build something like that with graphql-java, but there's nothing like it out of the box, as the goal of that lib is to implement the spec only.